# Telnet ip address at a given port

Tags: telnet

What's the difference between:

```
C:>telnet somehost 25
```

and

```
C:>telnet
Microsoft Telnet>open somehost 25
```

Why in the first case I immediately get a new completely black prompt, while the second case remain freezing to:

```
Connecting to host...
```

Help me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. Try `telnet /?` and the `help` command from inside telnet.

What you can see on the screen in the second case is just because launching a command from the telnet prompt has more verbosity.